# Flink Duplicates in Sink Write

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there a way to inspect the writes during a write to the Sink?

I am receiver this error `DynamoDbException: Provided list of item keys contains duplicate` during some writes to my dynamodb sink.  It is infrequent and I cannot determine the set of events that cause this to happen.  The exception obscures my ability to see which records are causing the issue.  Is there a way to inspect the writes after the write exception?  Can I insert my own exception handling in the write pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing to DynamoDB via the `batch_writer`, it supports de-duplication [per the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#batch-writing) by adjusting the `overwrite_by_pkeys` parameter as follows:

```
overwrite_by_pkeys=['partition_key', 'sort_key']
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm using the Flink DynamoDBSink and Element Converter:
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/dynamodb/

As far as I can tell it doesn't give me access to the lower level Dynamo libraries.  However, because of your suggestion, I did notice that there is a `setOverwriteByPartitionKeys` optional parameter.  I'm giving that a try.

Comment: For anyone else having this issue, `setOverwriteByPartitionKeys` successfully fixed the duplicate issue.

Comment: You may want to consider marking this as an answer for future users if it addressed your issue.